# When click on graph, zoom in perfectly, then back out with button click?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is there a way to fix a zoom by clicking on a shape. I am decent with excel, however I have no code to show.

PLease help, thanks:)

Comment: `ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100%` set zooming for the window. You can put it into simple macro and than associate it with your shape.

Comment: Thats great, thanks! however how about if there need to be a shift. The zoom focuses on the left and top i thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to zoom and shift:

```
Sub zoom_shift()

Dim SHP As Shape
Set SHP = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
Dim siLeft As Single
Dim siTop As Single

siLeft = SHP.Left
siTop = SHP.Top

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200

Application.Goto SHP.TopLeftCell, True

End Sub
```

However, you can need some adjustment according to your needs.

Comment: Both perfect answers for different applications, both came in handy. Thanks :)